# understanding operator lookup; which compiler is correct?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, operator-overloading

This may be asked before but I didn't have luck finding an answer...

I have an unordered container (i.e. a hash; we'll call it QHash, because it is, though this probably happens in any similar situation) that needs a comparison operator for it's key type.

Consider the following:

```
// foo.h
class Bar
{
public:
    class Foo {};
};

// foo.cpp
#include <QtCore/QHash>

namespace
{
    typedef Bar::Foo Foo;
    bool operator==(Foo const& a, Foo const& b) { return &a == &b; }
}

uint qHash(Foo const& foo) { return qHash(&foo); }

int main()
{
    QHash<Foo, int> hash;
    // do stuff with hash, e.g.:
    hash.insert(Foo(), 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Using G++, all is well. However, clang gives an error in the bowels of qhash.h about `invalid operands to binary expression` where trying to use `==` on instances of `Foo`. It seems to me that clang is either not finding or rejecting the definition of `operator==` in the anonymous namespace, probably due to different lookup rules than G++.

I am wondering, which compiler is correct?

p.s. I'm building in C++11 mode, in case it makes a difference.

Comment: Contents *do* matter. We'll need to so an actual compilable example and the error messages.

Comment: Good idea to make SO readers guess about what secret code produced the vaguely described behavior. I almost voted up just for that. I see that at least 4 persons have already done so, though, so I abstain.

Comment: @jrok, no, really they don't (in fact, empty will do nicely). The question is: "given the above, is it expected that QHash trying to use operator== on a pair of Foo would find the operator as it is defined?". GCC thinks "yes". Clang thinks "no". I am *not* asking how to fix it ("don't do that" / make the operator== public); I am wondering which is correct.

Comment: ...and before someone tells me I need to explain the concept of an unordered container... QHash is (obviously) a template class over `<Key, Value>` with an associated helper class `QHashNode<Key, Value>`  having a member `Key key` and method `(Key const& key0)` that does a `key0 == key`. Clang barfs here, complaining that it can't find a suitable `==`.

Comment: Well, do you have the same issue with `std::unordered_map` ?

Comment: And how is that `qHash` function related to anything?

Comment: qHash tells QHash how to compute the hash for a key type (i.e. roughly std::hash). The code won't compile without it, for reasons that should be obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ADL looks into the namespaces a class is defined in. Look
at
[basic.lookup.argdep]/2:
"For each argument type T in the function call, there is a set of zero
or more associated namespaces and a
set of zero or more associated classes to be considered. The sets of
namespaces and classes is determined
entirely by the types of the function arguments (and the namespace of
any template template argument).
Typedef names and using-declarations used to specify the types do not
contribute to this set."

Note the last sentence.

So, for the original example, the typedef in the namespace of the
operator doesn't help,
gcc is wrong and clang is right.

Comment: Thanks; this was spot on!

Comment: Except that the namespace where the operator is *used* also affect the lookup, and OP didn't both to tell us what namespace the calling code was in.

Answer (score 5):

This is a [known GCC bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/PR51577). Essentially, the problem is that GCC does not correctly implement two-phase name lookup for operator names. Your `operator==` is not found by unqualified lookup (because it is declared too late) and is not found by argument-dependent name lookup (because `::(anonymous namespace)` is not an associated namespace of `Bar::Foo`, so should not be considered inside the instantiation of `qHash`.

If you move the definition of `qHash` into the anonymous namespace, GCC will then reject the code, because its bug only applies to operator names and not to normal function names.

Answer (score -1):

Despite your claim that the choice of unordered container doesn't matter, the following self-contained fully standard code generates consistent errors on both g++ and clang -- neither one finds `operator==`.

```
#include <unordered_map>

// foo.h
class Bar
{
public:
    class Foo {};
};

// foo.cpp
namespace
{
    typedef Bar::Foo Foo;
    bool operator==(Foo const& a, Foo const& b) { return &a == &b; }
}

namespace std
{
  template <>
  struct hash<Foo>
  {
    std::size_t operator()(const Foo& k) const
    {
      return std::hash<const Foo*>()(&k);
    }
  };
}

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<Foo, int> hash;
    // do stuff with hash, e.g.:
    hash.emplace(Foo(), 5);
    return 0;
}
```

The important part of the error is

> error: no match for `operator==` (operand types are `const Bar::Foo` and `const Bar::Foo`)
>
> ```
>   { return __x == __y; }
> ```

Basically, if you want operators to be found by library code, stick them in an associated namespace of the class and let ADL do its thing.  Definitely don't use an anonymous namespace, unless the class itself is inside the anonymous namespace.

Comment: I said the contents of *the key class* don't matter. They don't. I *believed* that the container class "probably" doesn't matter, but apparently it does.

Comment: (Sorry; SO treats enter in comments as "yes, I wanted to post that"... wasn't done...) However, while I think you imply an answer, what I'm trying to ask is, should GCC be rejecting also the original code (as clang does)?

Comment: @Matthew: There's no way to know without the complete source code for your container.  If you want `operator==` found by *all* containers, put it in an associated namespace.

Comment: it's not "my" container... I guess you have never heard of Qt? See https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/5.3:src/corelib/tools/qhash.h

Comment: @Matthew: I have heard of it, but you have decided to use it.  Take ownership of your decision.  When you start taking dependencies on internal implementation details (and you are, since you are writing code that does not work if the standard `std::unordered_map` is substituted) then you need to treat those implementation details as if they were *your* code.  Otherwise you risk future Qt changes breaking your entire application.

Comment: @Matthew: My recommendation is to write your code in a way that works no matter whether the caller is in `namespace` std or not.  That gives you confidence that changes to implementation details won't break you.

Comment: @Matthew: BTW, a link to the Qt source isn't good enough.  Your entire question is still written about general containers, and you haven't included the parts of the error message that mention specific parts of the QHash code.  When you ask for help with something non-standard, you need to provide everything that you would be providing for errors in your own code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64518/discussion-between-matthew-and-ben-voigt).

Comment: @Matthew: I can't "just answer the question", because you aren't giving the necessary information that a correct answer depends on.  Your question contains NONE of the needed information, and your comments linked a 1104 line wall of code dump.  And still didn't identify the line and function where the error occurs.